# TestNG is not reading application properties file

Tags: java, spring-boot, testng

When I am running TestClass it is reading value from properties file. while application is reading properly.

**Here's how the test class looks like**

```
public class TestClass {
    @Mock 
    ABC abc;

    @Test
    public void testHealth() {
        Assert.assertEquals("OK",abc.health());
    }
}
```

**Here's how the class ABC looks like**

```
public class ABC {
    @Autowired 
    Properties props;
    public String health() {
            return props.getMessage(); // returning null
    }
}
```

I am seeing following error.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected [null] but found [OK]
Expected :null
Actual   :OK
```

while my properties file has message value.

Comment: Can you please help add a bit more context to your question. Its not very clear as to what you are trying to do. But on a high level, for you to be able to get Spring to inject the dependencies into your test class, you should be extending your test class from `org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`. Please see if [this](https://www.mkyong.com/unittest/testng-spring-integration-example/) tutorial helps you

Comment: I am using testng framework instead of junit.

Comment: I am using testng framework instead of junit. When I am running Test Class compiler is returning null for defined properties in application.properties. 

I tried different annotation like 
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Config.class,initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class) , @SpringBootTest but nothing worked.

Comment: Only when you would like to run a spring based TestNG test is when you need to be extending `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`. Have you tried looking at the tutorial link that I shared ? That should give you an idea.

Comment: Since mine is Springboot application I added @ContextConfiguration(classes = Config.class,initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)  and extended test class with AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests . But still it is not reading properties file.

Comment: I  followed this too:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-configfileapplicationcontextinitializer-test-utility